# Check if text exist in rest of Column, and if so, use info from that row it is in

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm after a way to a cell to check another cell that I'm inputting text into, and for it to see if that text value is the same anywhere else in the column, and if so, it grabs the number value which is in the same column as itself but in the row of the text that checked for.

[image: 1]]

So if you use picture, you can see I've currently got E7 selected. I'm wanting it to check the "GOLF COURSE" column for any other row that contains the same text it has in it's own row. For this it's "Course1". I'd like it to check through the rest of column B if there are any matches for "Course1" which there is in B3. If it matches I'm wanting it to then use the value that's in same column as it (E) but the same row as the matched text in column B. In this case I would want it to copy the value that is in E3.
If there wasn't a match (as it's a new course lets say) then I need to be able to just click on the cell and input the numbers needed, which I would be able to do anyway but just throwing it in for sake of info.

I've tried all sorts of googling and thinking how I could possibly do it but it's too difficult for my amateur knowledge of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$B7)>1,INDEX(E:E,MATCH($B7,$B:$B,0)),"New")
```

[image]

I added a `COUNTIF` check to ensure that the same course exists more than once in column B, without it, you would be getting a circular reference formula (which would also happen with the above formula if the same course appears more than once, but you use this formula on the first occurrence of that course, so make sure do not use it the first time you fill out the PAR scores for a particular course).

Comment: You sir are a saint! I could kiss you! Thanks so much works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

## Merged Cells Messing With INDEX/MATCH

### The Formula

Copy the following formula into cell `E7`:

```
=IF(AND($B7<>"",$D7="Par"),IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0)),"Par",INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0))),IF(AND($B6<>"",$D7="Strokes"),IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)),"Strokes",INDEX(E$3:E4,MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)+1)),""))
```

---

### Image

[image]

### How

We are creating the formula in cell `E7`.

**MATCH**

Syntax: `MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array,match_type)`

- We will use `MATCH` to find the position of `COURSE1` in the above
  cells of column `B`.
- The 1st argument is `lookup_value` which will be the cell in the same
  row of our row (`7`) in column `B`: `B7` where we will lock only the
  column (we will not be searching in other columns): `$B7`.
- The 2nd argument `lookup_array` will be a range. The first cell will be
  cell `B3` whose row and column we'll lock, because we will always
  start the search from this cell in every other cell to the left or
  below: `$B$3`. The last cell will be `B5` where we will lock only the
  column: `$B5`.
- And finally we will use `0` as the parameter of the 3rd argument
  `match_type` to find an exact match.
- Now were ready to write our `MATCH` formula:

  ```
     =MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0)
  ```

  Which will return **1** i.e. an exact (`0`) match of `B7` was found
  in the **1st** cell of range `B3:B5`.
- We don't want `1` (`E3`), but the value in the cell (`5`).

**INDEX**

The `INDEX` function has 2 syntaxes where we will use the 2nd:

Syntax 2: `INDEX(reference,row_num,column_num,area_num)`

Since were using a one-column range we can safely omit the arguments `row_num` and `column_num`, which leaves us with:

Modified Syntax: `INDEX(reference,area_num)`

- The `INDEX` function used this way will return the `area_num`-th value
  of `reference` i.e. in our case if `area_num` is `1` it will return the
  `1st` value in our column range, if it is `2`, then the `2nd`, etc.
- The 1st argument `reference` will be the same sized range of our
  `MATCH` range in column `E`: `$E$3:$E5` where we will remove the
  column locks because we also want to return results for other
  columns: `E$3:E5`.
- The 2nd argument `area_num` will be our `MATCH` formula.
- Our current formula looks like this:

  ```
     =INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0))
  ```

  which will return the value of cell `E3`: `5`.

**Final Adjustments: `IF`, `AND` and `ISERROR`**

That would have been almost (Error Checking) all if the cells in column `B` weren't merged. Therefore we have to use `IF` to determine if the row in which we're writing the formula contains either `Par` or `Strokes` and adjust our so far created formula for both conditions:

```
=IF($D7="Par",INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0))
=IF($D7="Strokes",INDEX(E$3:E4,MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)+1)

=IF($D7="Par",INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0)),$D7="Strokes",INDEX(E$3:E4,MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)+1))
```

---

and (3rd condition) check in column `B` if there is a value in the row where we're creating the formula for a row containing `Par`, or the row above for a row containing `Strokes`, using `AND`:

```
=IF(AND($B7<>"",$D7="Par"),INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0)),IF(AND($B6<>"",$D7="Strokes"),INDEX(E$3:E4,MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)+1),""))
```

---

Finally we have to add some error checking, because if the match was not found the formula will produce and `#N/A` error:

```
=IF(AND($B7<>"",$D7="Par"),IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0)),"Par",INDEX(E$3:E5,MATCH($B7,$B$3:$B5,0))),IF(AND($B6<>"",$D7="Strokes"),IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)),"Strokes",INDEX(E$3:E4,MATCH($B6,$B$3:$B4,0)+1)),""))
```

---

Now we are ready to copy the formula to the right and below as far as we need.

Comment: Hmm just noticed you added your answer here and wanted to say that the OP might not need the formula to fill in the Strokes, because those will be updated live. In the context of Golf, par remains the same for each course and each hole, whereas strokes will vary with a player's play. It looks to me that OP wants to track a player's game progress and did not want to manually fill the par information if it was already entered once before.

Comment: @Jerry: Let's say Golf isn't my strong side, obviously. But could I have concluded this somehow from OP's question considering my first statement? And finally should I delete the post?

Comment: Oh no, it's not my intention to tell you do delete the post (I'm sorry if it came out that way), because it might be useful in a different context and SO is not only intended to be for the question asked only, but to problems that people in general might face, so your problem might be useful to someone else, if they stumble on that question. At the end of the day though it's up to you.

Comment: @Sorry for bothering, no apologies necessary. I was more interested in the answer of how could I have concluded from OP's question that I don't need to match the values of strokes considering I don't play golf that often. In short: what did I miss?

Comment: I wouldn't say you missed anything; but it was more about how the question could have been improved. A picture helps a lot, but then I think some better explanation could have helped. It took me a while to understand the requirements, and honestly, I probably would have gone the path you picked had I not known a bit of golf from the video games I've played ^^;